# When do system access policies start to become source of security incidents?

Tags: password-policy

Consider the assumption we are dealing with systems handling secret information which is crucial for an organization's existence. I would like to know what is a good balance between security requirements and usability when it comes to password complexity, password change policy, multi-authentication factor requirements and so on...

Are there best practices for this topic?

I know several situation which might jeopardize security due to a severe policy:

- Writing down passwords since they are either so difficult to remember or because you have to change it so often.
- Intentionally letting the PKI card in the laptops even when unattended.
- Saving password in plain-text either. Even worse when they use Excel files offering a vast menu of users and passwords to hackers.

Comment: There's no good answer for "where's the line between too loose and too tight a security policy"; it's opinion based, varies from organization to organization and even then is hardly ever quantifiable unless there's a compromise that gets tied back to policy with 20-20 hindsight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many organizations face this problem, with employees being the "weakest link" in security. Overall, password based authentication has proven to be a gap. Employees cannot reasonably be expected to remember eleven or twelve passwords that they must change monthly. We recently faced this issue in my organization and came to a few conclusions.

1. Two-factor authentication coupled with a single sign on solution (SSO) will make employees happier and reduce the risk profile of multiple stand alone password entries.
2. For two-factor authentication, media devices such as flash drives are not the best form, but it is better than nothing. Employees will leave them in their workstations unfortunately. A stronger form of two-factor would be implementing a cellular verification (Duo Mobile offers this). When a user attempts to sign on, they will be asked to check their cell phone. If it is a smart phone with the Duo Mobile app, a notification will appear in their task bar asking for approval of the login. If not, text messaging features can be used for an access code. This can also work with an office phone (not the best option, but requires the attacker to be physically at the employees desk).
3. If you are going to use a very strong two-factor authentication, SSO is a must to keep employees from becoming overly agitated. The two-factor authentication should be configured for a password vault which has browser plugins for SSO and stores other passwords for retrieval, allowing this solution to work with applications that do not support an SSO method. During our research, LastPass and AuthLite had these options available. They also had features which would manage password changes for employees, automatically changing the employees passwords after an expiration period. Since the passwords were system generated, it took away the password re-use headache.

In the end, we went with a password vault that offered SSO capabilities coupled with flash drive two-factor authentication (for cost purposes) to access the employees vault.